# JmeterClarification on Mutiple scenario at same time

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I  have read about the same scenario on blog . 
I have few queries to related . Can anyone please correct me if am wrong in  understanding .

My Questions ,
I have tried running 2 Thread Groups under Single Test Plan

```
Thread Group1 : User scenario
Thread Group2 : Admin scenario
```

So here the scenarios are different which are present under single Test Plan .
Suppose I want to check the performance of this Test plan .

To acheieve this scenario :

Test Plan >> Make sure that check box is unchecked for "Run Thread Groups  consecutively"
My  understanding here is **" As per the above scenario i.e ThreadGroup 1 & 2 will be  started simulatenously** .
If this is the case then reports  generated , we can consider the values generated are for both ThreadGroups 1 & 2 . Can I consider in this way ?

Whether we can  consider the reports generated are for both Thread Groups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your understanding about thread group execution is correct. Those thread groups will execute simulateously.

If you have added reporters to testplan they will contain and show results for both thread groups like below,

[image]

If you have added reporters to each thread group seperately then they will contains reports for that threadgroup only like below,

[image]

This all depends on scope of component and execution. This applies to non-gui test also because script scoping is referred while writing data to jtl file.

Comment: Thanks Kate . btw I have one more query , So from the above scenario we can conclude that Jmeter doesn't support simulatenously exeution and Report also doesn't show that it executed simulatenously . It will be in sequential order right ?

Comment: Is their any way we can acheive  the reports for Simulatenous execution of two different Threads  ? Can you please  help me

Comment: I am sorry I didn't read your question properly Updating answer a bit. Jmeter Default supports simultaneous execution of threadgroups unless you checked execute sequentially. Yes from reports you cannot make out that execution was concurrent or sequential. Approach 2 in answer should used in that case.

Comment: "Is their any way we can acheive the reports for Simulatenous execution of two different Threads". If you are using more than 1 thread in each threadgroup then all threads for a thread group will execute at the same time and Reports are just showing results of execution independent of execution.